# Standalone Socket.IO server in Java

Tags: java, websocket, socket.io

I am looking for a simple Socket.IO server written in Java.

I am familiar with [this one](http://code.google.com/p/socketio-java/), but it has a dependency on servlets, which I am not using in my application.

I am looking for something similar to [this](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket), but supports all of the Socket.IO protocol, not just the WebSocket part.

**EDIT**: this also means no Jetty, etc.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this lib:

https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio

Based on high performance socket lib Netty.

It supports latest protocol of Socket.IO server.

Comment: Has anyone tested this framework and is it production ready ?

Comment: @PiniCheyni I have used it. Works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Given that most production-capable Java-based servers are based on the Servlet standard, I don't believe any such implementation exists.

Comment: Well, this isn't mean to serve as a web server, I want to expose a streaming API that is accessible via the web. Socket.IO makes the most sense for that. I guess I get to write one now. Fun.

Comment: Hehe. Depending on your definition of fun :). I'd argue that going with something like Tomcat with the NIO handler and the Comet implementation gets you where you want to go faster, BUT I can understand not wanting to deal with all the extra layering that the J2EE stuff adds on.